# Is this a valid definition of independent assortment?

Tags: genetics

"Allelic combinations separate randomly. I.e. a parent might be Aa and Bb for two traits but that doesn't necessarily mean the gametes will strictly be AB or ab but any of a number of combinations. I.e. blue eyes does not imply short height or something."

Answer (score 1):

That's a valid explanation, but not definition. Mendel's law of independent assortments states that during the formation of gametes, the alleles for one trait segregate independently of the alleles of another trait.

Answer (score 1):

```
The Law of Independent Assortment:
Alleles for different traits are distributed to sex cells (& offspring) independently of one another.
```

This one is like written on the stone in my mind!